# rails -v The system cannot find the path specified. Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I'm just starting an online full stack dev. course and am ultra new to coding in general so when I do my rails bundle install @ http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows I have gone through the complete install and all updates needed but my rails -v is still not working even after re-installing everything, I'm using windows 10 64bit. And I'm stuck at this point and have spent lots of time trying to find out what the problem could be with nothing working yet? Attached is a screen shot if that helps.[rails -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ3AQ.png) Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0` and edit the .bat files (such as rails.bat). They have a hard-coded path that might be wrong. Change the path to:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF :WinNT
@"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```